# How to left and right align list items for navbar in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to place the nav bar using bootstrap to place few list items.
In the image shown below, I want "Register" and "Login" list items to be moved to the right (aligned in the red-box position) keeping the nav bar visible in white from left to right inside the "container" class.

[image: Navbar]

Below is my html. Please suggest corrections to this.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-static-top">        
    <div class="container">             
        <ul class="nav navbar-default">                                    
                <li><a href="#"><span class="icon-heart"></span> Wish List(0)</a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><span class="icon-user"></span> Account</a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><span class="icon-shopping-cart"></span> Cart</a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><span class="icon-file"></span> Checkout</a></li>
                <ul class="nav navbar-right">
                    <li><a href="#">Register</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Login</a></li>      
                </ul>
        </ul>            
    </div>
</nav>
```

====

## Update 1

I tried the below html to get somewhat close. I need the navbar within the container width.

```
<div class="container">
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav nav-header navbar-default">
        <li><a href="#"><span class="icon-heart"></span> Wish List(0)</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#"><span class="icon-user"></span> My Account</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#"><span class="icon-shopping-cart"></span> Cart</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#"><span class="icon-file"></span> Checkout</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="nav navbar-default pull-right">
        <li><a href="#">Register</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Login</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

But I am not getting **the grey background for the navbar in-between** as shown in the screenshot (Yellow box). [The second navbar is just to indicate the page width.]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

In your example you're missing the relevant code that supports Bootstraps [Navbar](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar). See the Docs.

Seperate the two `<ul class="nav navbar-nav">`: one standard and one with `navbar-right` added.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
  <div class="container">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false"> <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>

      </button>

    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="#"><span class="icon-heart"></span> Wish List(0)</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#"><span class="icon-user"></span> Account</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#"><span class="icon-shopping-cart"></span> Cart</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#"><span class="icon-file"></span> Checkout</a>

        </li>

      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#">Register</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Login</a>

        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Thank you, but my requirement is the navbar should be inside the container but remain resized to the container width.

Comment: Thank you. I was looking into how to make items in the nav right align themselves... `.navbar-right` was exactly what I needed.